# Push array and loop until the array length reach 3

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, push, settimeout

I am trying to push array a value until it reach the length of 3. I want also add delay to the loop. Any suggestion to fix the code. If the condition is met, break and go to next function. I am greatly appreciate it!

```
let array = [];
let eachEverySeconds = 1;
//function fetchCoinPrice(params) { //BinanceUS Fee: 0.00075 or 0.075%
function Firstloop() {
  for (x = 0; x < 4; x++) {

    setTimeout(function() {
      function fetchCoinPrice() {
        binance.prices(function(error, ticker) {
          //array.push(ticker.BNBBTC);    
          //while(array.length<3){


          //if (array.length<4){
          array.push(ticker.BNBBTC);
          console.log("1", array);
          //}else {}//if (array.length === 3) { break; }
          // array.shift();

        });
      }
    }, 1000)
  }
}
// setInterval(Firstloop, eachEverySeconds * 1000);
Firstloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to save the interval into a variable that you can then use `clearInterval()` on.

Here's a mockup of what you're trying to accomplish.

```js
var array = [];
var maxLength = 3;
var delay = 250; //I shortened your delay
var ticker = {}; //I'll use this to simulate your ticker object

var looper = setInterval(function() { 
      ticker.BNBBTC = Math.random(); //populating your ticker property w/random value

      if (array.length < maxLength) {
         array.push(ticker.BNBBTC);
      } else {
         console.log("Stopping the looper.");
         clearInterval(looper);
         console.log("Here are the contents of array");
         console.log(array);
      }
}, delay);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I've understood your purpose as there are many commented codes there but if you want to run a function for three times and run it again after a second with new prices or ... may be this code helps you:

```js
let array = [];
let eachEverySeconds = 1;

const loopArray = (array) => {
    setTimeout(async () => {
        if (array.length === 3) return;
        let price = Math.random() * 10;
        array.push(price);
        await loopArray(array);
    }, 1000 * eachEverySeconds);
    console.log(array);
};

loopArray(array);
```

Comment: Wonderful, I like how everyone has their way to program. Thank you for your effort!